# Kalman Filter corrected by known path

Tags: kalman-filter

I am trying to get filtered velocity/spacial data from noisy position data from a tracked vehicle. I have a set of noisy position/time `data = (x_i,y_i,t_i)` and a known curve along which the vehicle is traveling, `curve = (x(s),y(s)),` where `s` is total distance along the curve. I can run a Kalman filter on the `data,` but I don't know how to constrain it to the 'road' without throwing out data that is too far from the road, which I don't want to do.

Alternately, I'm trying to estimate the value of `s` along the constrained path with position data that is noisy in `x` and `y`

Does anyone have an idea of how to merge the two types of data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what a Kalman filter does? Fundamentally, it assigns a probability to each possible state given just observables. In simple cases, this doesn't use *a priori* knowledge. But in your case, you can simply set the off-road estimates to zero and renormalizing the remaining probabilities.

Note: this isn't throwing out *observables* which are too far off the road, or even discarding *outcomes* which are too far off. It means that an apparent off-road position strongly increases the probabilities of an outcome on, but near the edge of the road.

If you want the model to allow small excursions away from the road, you can use a fast decaying function to model the low but non-zero probability of a car being off the road.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by: "Note: this isn't throwing out observables which are too far off the road, or even discarding outcomes which are too far off. It means that an apparent off-road position strongly increases the probabilities of an outcome on, but near the edge of the road."  If I understand correctly, which I'm not sure I do, how would this help for very noisy position data? Additionally, does this do anything about wildly inaccurate data that is nonetheless along the expected path?

Comment: @Necarion: The question in the first sentence wasn't rhetorical. Some people use "Kalman" as a black box algorithm: throw numbers in, get numbers out. And then you can only modify the algorithm by tinkering with the numbers before and after, but not with the content of the black box. But if you realize that inside the black box there's a model of the world, then you can add your road to that model.

Comment: @Necarion: As for the "very noisy data" situation, with _a priori_ knowledge that the vehicle stays on the road, note that in this case the bulk of of the available information comes from the _a priori_ information, and the measurements add very little information. It's not unexpected that this basically ends up estimating the speed along the road, but not the speed perpendicular to the road. Is that useful? I can't tell, it depends on the application, but it might very well be.

Comment: I have basic intuitive understanding of how the Kalman filter works, but not the details.  The filter does seem appropriate here, because I do want to estimate the speed along the road. I'm just inherently uncomfortable throwing away data, particularly in this case because the data isn't gathered very frequently, and throwing away data points has a high cost in spatial resolution.  Also, I'm a bit uncomfortable with a model that treats unphysical jumps differently if they're along the path or off it, but the Kalman filter might handle that in its nuts and bolts.

Comment: @Necarion: That's precisely why I suggest don't throwing away data. As for treating "jumps" differently when they're "off the road", I don't know what you mean by "jumps". The observables which are off-road are most likely/certainly off-road because of measurement noise, not because the real position is off-road. That makes off-road observations fundamentally different.

Comment: Okay, I think I finally understand what you meant above: you're suggesting 'snapping' the off-road data points to the nearest on-road coordinate (and potentially weighting those points based on distance as well)? What I meant by "jumps" is large changes in along-road motion due to measurement noise. I suppose the Kalman filter will deal with that part, though?  Thank you for your patience on this question.

Comment: @Necarion: No, that is entirely not what I suggest. Not at all. You do not mess with the measurements. You don't discard them, you don't change them.That utterly destroys your ability to apply statistics. What you alter is the probability function. But you really should read up on the principles of the Kalman filter,

Answer (score 0):

You could have as states the distance s along the path, and the rate of change of s. The position observations X and Y will then be non-linear functions of the state (assuming your track is not a line) so you'll need to use an extended or unscented filter.